# Matrix invertibility proof?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

Can it be proven that $A^\top  A$ is invertible given just the fact that:

> if $A^\top Ay = \theta$
>   then $Ay = \theta$?

Here $y$ is a vector and $\theta$ is the vector zero.

Comment: The property “for all $y$, if $A^TAy=0$ then $Ay=0$” holds for *any* matrix (even not square).

Comment: What it does mean is that $A^T A$ is invertible if the null space of $A$ contains only $\theta$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is not enough to show $A^T A$ is invertible.  The claim holds when $A$ is the zero matrix (since $Ay=0$ is automatically true), yet in this case $A^T A$ is not invertible.

In fact the highlighted fact is true for **every** matrix, whether square or rectangular, singular or invertible (assuming we work over the reals and not some other field).  If $A^T A y = 0$ then $y^T A^T A y = 0$, but the LHS is just $\| Ay \|$, so $Ay$ must be the zero vector.

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ is injective then $A^TA$ is invertible. Maybe that's what you mean?